# IIS Redirect some pages to new server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp-classic

I apologize if this has been answered, but I've had no luck. I'm new to a position at a company and don't have a great deal of experience with external customer facing web sites.

Currently, they have a Windows Server 2008 install running IIS 7 which serves up mostly classic ASP pages for a particular domain, call it mydomain.com.

The plan is to trim the site and eventually migrate to an ASP.NET MVC 5 site running on Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5. In the short term there are some pages that are essentially self-contained apps that need updating. There's still a good bit of planning that needs to be done to migrate all the various parts of the site (many just bolted on self-contained "apps"). I'd prefer to not have to try and modify or reconstruct things on the existing server. It would be trivial from a resource standpoint to standup a new server and host the newly revised pages on the new server.

The ultimate question is, can I host just the new pages on the new server and the keep the old ones on the old server? How would I go about redirecting the traffic for the pages on the new server from the old? Am I looking at a DNS sub-domain, in essence, or is there a more practical option?

Thanks in advance for your help. If there is information missing from this post, I will happily update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes. Longer answer: If you're going to have two servers, you will have to employ a subdomain, as you can't attach the same domain to multiple IP addresses. But, as you migrate one bit of the old site, you can add redirects on the older server to hit the new area on the your subdomain. It's pretty standard. With IIS7, you'll need to install the [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

The only slight kink is if you need to share anything between the two sites: sessions, authentication, etc. If that's the case, you'll have to do some extra work. I haven't worked much with classic ASP, but for sessions, a cursory Google search came up with: [How to Share Session State Between Classic ASP and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx). Auth is harder. The only thing I could find was a v[ery old Microsoft blog showing how to share FormsAuth in ASP.NET with a classic ASP app](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-integrating-asp-net-security-with-classic-asp-and-non-asp-net-urls). It was written against ASP.NET 2.0, and MVC 5 with the new Identity components is a totally different beast (FormsAuth isn't even used anymore). You might be pretty much out of luck on that front.

Comment: Chris. Thanks, that gives me a sense about where to go. It's nice to know I was in the right neighborhood, anyway.